# Time from web clients to inform SES about a Complaint - Spam email

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, spam-prevention, amazon-ses, amazon-sns

I'm sending emails using amazon SES. While doing some tests, I marked some emails (using different accounts) as SPAM in Gmail and other clients but I haven't received any SNS notification which I have set up.

I have used the emails that [Amazon provides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html) to test and they work, but when trying with my real emails, it doesn't.

Comment: Is your account in production or development mode?  Did you file a complaint from one of your authorized sender accounts?

Comment: @ruben did you try with Hotmail?

Comment: @ruben did you try with Outlook Desktop in Win or Mail in OSx?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about email deliverability, not about programming.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Gmail has a different complaint feedback loop system, they only send reports about complaints to selected ESPs. If you mark some email as Spam they only move automatically this and future new emails to Spam folder and don't notify.

I tested with a Hotmail account and I received a complaint notification from SNS.

Comment: Exactly. Gmail *DOES NOT* send spam/bounce notifications to email originating from SES. They only have a handful of providers that they allow in their feedback loop.